# What's the best way to return the name of the current property?

Tags: c#

This code shows a property that calls out to a method to get that property's name:

```
public string Foo { get { return MyName(); } }

string MyName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] 
    string propertyName = null)
{
    return propertyName;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: The 'next' or the 'name'? Body doesn't match title.

Comment: the title question makes no sense.

Comment: And, why would you ever need this?  You already know the name.  YOU MADE IT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Property Name in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552712/getting-property-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Potential duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4364888/1220971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That arguably is the best way as of .Net 4.5 having replaced the previous .net call such as

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
```

where the user had to hard code that information. Now in .Net 4.5 the call looks like this:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged();
```

thanks to

```
void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

See [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist) for other strategies.